# Android WebView's window.innerWidth is coming 313

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple webview with javascript enabled. And I am loading a web page inside that. Page has a javascript function which emits the window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight. When I run this on Nexus one, innerWidth and innerHeight are coming 313x533. But when I load that page in android browser then they're coming 320x452.
I couldn't find any reasonable explanation for that. In my html page I have declared the following viewport.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```