# Webview Width compared to Android Browser Width

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

So i've created a few html pages to embed into an application via WebView, the pages themselves work fine in the normal android browser HOWEVER within the WebView module the page's width is only 313, and it allows a bit of a horizontal scroll, this does not occur in a normal browser in Android.

So the desired width is `320px`, WebView is outputting `313px` but still allows a horizontal scroll (of a few pixels).

Below is my code for the layout, I assume Android is injecting some inline styles into the webview that I am not aware of, was wondering if anyone had the same problem?

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/help_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You might want to look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970045/android-webviews-window-innerwidth-is-coming-313
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some differences between `Webview` and  native browser:

[Android WebView VS Phone Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373585/android-webview-vs-phone-browser)
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9fb826412233b9b4

Did you try `setWebChromeClient()`?
[What's the difference between setWebViewClient vs. setWebChromeClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient)